# Android beacon library - multiple regions monitoring

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I use Android beacon library so I need help with some matters:

If I understood correctly, we must have just one RegionBootstrap.
Why? Is it possible to have a list of RegionBootstraps?

I tried to implement that and it works okay. What difficulties could arise from this approach?

Replacement for my logic would be one RegionBootstrap with multiple regions, but then I cannot remove all regions from it. Why did the author skip to add that?

I have guest mode and user mode and every of them has different regions, so I need to change them in appropriate time. What approach would be the best?
One regionBootstrap with multiple regions? Or multiple RegionBootstraps?

Thank you

UPDATE: I add 4 regions to regionBootstrap and I am able to find entered region. After that, I remove those 4 regions and set 2 new regions, but device still finds one of the 4 regions set before.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

A few tips:

- `RegionBootstrap` is designed to be one instance per application.  Only use one, and only construct it once.
- If you want to monitor multiple regions, you can use this constructor:  `RegionBootstrap(BootstrapNotifier application, List<Region> regions)` e.g. `new RegionBootstrap(this, regions);`
- If you want to **change** the regions being monitored by your `RegionBootstrap` after you have constructed one, don't make a new `RegionBootstrap`.  Simply use:

  `BeaconMananager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
  // Stop monitoring old region
  beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(oldRegion);
  // Start monitoring new region
  beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(newRegion);`

Comment: Okat, thanks, I already read this, but I dont have a region at the time I construct RegionBootstrap. Because of that, I create dummy region, but I cannot stop monitoring it. StopMonitoringBeaconInRegion does not work..Or at least, getMonitoredRegions () does not work. It always returns 1, even after stopping.

Comment: Is it possible to add empty RegionBootstrap which does nothing until regions are set by beaconManager?

Comment: And what is the purpose of addRegion and removeRegion from RegionBootstrap, if I must use beaconManager to change monitoring regions?

Comment: If you don't want to monitor any region at startup, you can pass an empty list of regions to the constructor that takes the `List<Region> regions` parameter.  The `addRegion` and `removeRegion` methods on `RegionBootstrap` are very similar to calling on the `BeaconManager`, but have the advantage of protecting against exceptions in some race conditions.   Using the methods on `RegionBootstrap` is a better idea.  Finally, when stopping monitoring, it is critical that you pass the same string identifier in the `Region` object as you used start monitoring, otherwise it will not stop.

Comment: Okay, I tested all you said, and after stopping monitoring, number of monitored regions is 0, but it still finds doors. Number of ranging regions is not null. Should I stop ranging too?

Comment: It turns out that newest versions are much more complicated to use than versions before... Because of didEnterRegion and similar things

Comment: I have 4 regions when in user mode. After logout, I remove all regions from bootstrapRegion. Monitored regions are removed but why ranging regions are not remove? After that, I login as guest and I still see that region is found, even if number of regions that I set (bootstrapRegion.addRegion) is 0. Number of ranging regions is 1 (previously set for user).
Is is possible to add functions for stopping everything? User mode, add 4 regions -> find one of them = great. Guest mode, remove all regions from monitored and ranging list?

Comment: Ranging and monitoring are different operations.  You simply need to make a call to the beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region) to stop.

Comment: @davidgyoung calling `beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(oldRegion)` throws `android.os.RemoteException: The BeaconManager is not bound to the service.  Call beaconManager.bind(BeaconConsumer consumer) and wait for a callback to onBeaconServiceConnect()`. But you cannot call `beaconManager.bind()` passing an Application that implements BootstrapNotifier. How do you remove regions added to a `RegionBootstrap` that you have no longer a reference to?